# Building imported into Gazebo not visible in Rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey, I am trying to import a complete building model into Gazebo (including the interiors like tables, chairs etc.). I am not sure if my approach is correct and I am in need your some assistance.

I converted the building file format into a .dae file and successfully imported it into gazebo by calling it as a mesh. Unfortunately, when I spawn my quadrotor to visualize the building, it is not detected by the camera or the LIDAR (but I am able to visualize the building in the gazebo environment, and all the interiors are visible)

I suspect this has to do with the material of the building when it is being imported into gazebo?! but i am unsure how to edit or change the same. When I tried spawning the quadrotor on the building, it fell right on to the ground plane ( is the building not physically present or created in the gazebo? not sure why).

Can someone guide me on where I am going wrong? Need some help here. I've attached my world file [C:\fakepath\world.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15071469357643019.world)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17384/building-imported-into-gazebo-not-visible-in-rviz/) by [kumar09](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3904/kumar09/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Did you add collisions to the building? The lidar sensor detects collisions in a model. However, you should be able to see the camera images in Rbiz. I would check and verify that images are being published to the ROS image topic

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumar09](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3904/kumar09/) on 2017-10-03**:
Oh, I did not do that as it was blocking the windows or doors, but i will be sure to give it a shot soon. Also, I checked the image topics it is printing properly though.